# What license are the hats published on?

Tags: discussion, licensing, winter-bash-2015

I really love the way my actual hat is improving my avatar.
Would I be allowed to make a copy of that hat and edit it in my avatar after the event is over?

Comment: Meta is simply *brimming* with licensing questions today.

Answer (score 62):

### Go nuts.

Technically, we own them, but you're free to use them as you see fit.

Obligatory hat tip:

(Yeah, I did that.)

They were brought to life by talented illustrator [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com/), who we'd recommend wholeheartedly should you find yourself with any freelance illustration needs.

Comment: Are you willing to state that in writing via certified mail? Our plan is to print the images and put them on physical hats and sell them online

Comment: @self, not a problem. You just need to submit a formal request, penned in the blood of a newborn unicorn, and delivered to our HQ via horse (or griffin).  On parchment sealed with the king's sigil.  (The current king, not that last bozo.)

Comment: @Jaydles I'm the king of my castle. Does that count?